# Apache POI setPrintArea to A4 page size

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I'm working with the Apache POI API to generate .xls files, and I want to set the printArea of my file.

I know there is a funcion called `setPrintArea()` but this one receive as parameters start and end row and column of my print area.

I want to know, if there is a way to set my print area for each sheet with the size of an A4 paper (210mmx290mm)

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For each `Sheet` in the workbook, get its `PrintSetup` object and call [`setPaperSize`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PrintSetup.html#setPaperSize(short)) on it, passing the appropriate `PrintSetup` constant: `A4_PAPERSIZE`.

```
mySheet.getPrintSetup().setPaperSize(PrintSetup.A4_PAPERSIZE);
```