# Apache POI page break in excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hi guys I just want to ask about how to remove the page break in column N in excel using the Apache poi in Java. I've already set up in my code that my print area is until column P. But when I try to print the generated excel it always set that the page break is in column N.

[image: Generated Excel]

How can I adjust the page break in column using Apache poi on java?

Comment: Looks like its only possible to set specific page sizes. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785386/apache-poi-setprintarea-to-a4-page-size)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: No there is [Sheet.setAutobreaks](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setAutobreaks-boolean-) and [Sheet.setFitToPage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setFitToPage-boolean-) which then could be combinated with [PrintSetup.setFitWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PrintSetup.setFitWidth-short-) and `PrintSetup.setFitHeight`. But the question is not clear about what exactly is the goal. There is not even code shown at all.

Comment: @AxelRichter The goal is to have the page break on column P rather than column N. With the methods you mentioned, I can't think of any way to set the page size to something specific as columns, yet alone pixels. So I would be happy to see an answer from you achieving exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is that at print all columns (`A:P`) fit to one page width, then one could solve this using [Scale a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/scale-a-worksheet-34a91eb5-8b4e-4a8a-ab28-b6492012eaae).

The following code uses [Sheet.setAutobreaks](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setAutobreaks-boolean-) and [Sheet.setFitToPage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getFitToPage--) combinated with [PrintSetup.setFitWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PrintSetup.html#setFitWidth-short-) and [PrintSetup.setFitHeight](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PrintSetup.html#setFitHeight-short-) to set the print setup to scale to fit. The width is set to fit all columns to 1 page width and the height is set automatic, so multiple pages are used when enough rows are present.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcelAllColumnsFitToOnePageWidth {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  for (int r = 0; r < 200; r++) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
   for (int c = 0; c < 16; c++) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
    cell.setCellValue("Lorem ipsum");
    if (r==0) sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);
   }
  }

  sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
  sheet.setFitToPage(true);
  PrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
  printSetup.setFitHeight((short)0);
  printSetup.setFitWidth((short)1);


  String fileout = (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook)?"Excel.xls":"Excel.xlsx";
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileout);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```